# Authentication using request scoped context with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, jersey

I am trying to create custom "userContext" as a SpringBean with request scope but I am unable to do so. Basically I have a Jersey REST api and I want to do authentication and authorization using my custom filters in which I autowire my "userContext" bean. The process looks like this:

1. REST API called (I expect Spring to create new instance of userContext bean)
2. AuthenticationFilter autowires new instance of userBean and populates it
3. AuthorizationFilter autowires the same instance which is populated now and authorize the user

When i first call the REST api (after server restart), it works as expected, but any other call fails, because AutorizationFilter gets an empty instance of userBean. I expect some fundamental misunderstanding of scopes on my part.

Btw: I'd like to avoid using ThreadLocal directly since Request scope should take care of it

I would like to know, why authorizationFilter doesn't see the populated version of the userBean and why the first call works. Thanks in advance for any help.

Just some parts of the code:

```
@Secured({Role.ADMIN}) //custom annotation
@GET
@Path("{id}")
public Response getUserById(@PathParam("id") Long id) throws IOException, MainException {

@Secured //custom annotation
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
@Scope(value="request", proxyMode= ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter 
    @Autowired
    private User userContext;


@Secured //custom annotation
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)
@Scope(value="request", proxyMode= ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class AuthorizationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private User userContext;


@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Component
@Scope(value = "request",  proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class User extends ModelBase implements Serializable {
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are building your own authentication, and not using Spring Security?

Comment: Teaching purposes + more control over the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Providers are not request scoped, I had to inject whole ApplicationContext so I could directly modify the right instance of userContext bean (which is request scoped). Basically I did something like this in both filters:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

    User userBean=applicationContext.getBean(User.class);
    ....
    userBean.setSomething("aaa");
```

Then I could just autowire such bean in my REST Resources, because they are request scoped by defaul:

```
@Component
@Api(value="/users", description = "Endpoint for Users listing")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, Constants.API_VERSIONS.V1_HEADER_XML, Constants.API_VERSIONS.V1_HEADER_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, Constants.API_VERSIONS.V1_HEADER_XML, Constants.API_VERSIONS.V1_HEADER_JSON})
@Path("/users")
public class UserResource {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserResource.class);

    @Autowired
    private User authenticatedUser;
```

This solution should be viable and resistent against thread race conditions etc.